# Email changes in hudson

Tags: email, hudson, cvs

I am looking for a way in hudson to email the changes from a project, only if there are changes. I see how to email changes when a build is successful but I only want to send the email if the build is successful and there were changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (not tested) the Jenkins [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) can help you:

> This plugin extends Hudson's built in email notification functionality by giving you more control.  It provides customization of 3 areas.
>
> - **Triggers** - Select the conditions that should cause an email notification to be sent.
> - **Content** - Specify the content of each triggered email's subject and body.
> - **Recipients** - Specify who should receive a email when it is triggered.

You might need to rebuild that plugin to add your specific trigger condition, like in [this example](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7859).